# Publishing an event in an aggregate within a transaction

Tags: cqrs

I've seen a CQRS sample project that uses stateful aggregate roots persisted using an ORM.  Let me set up the question in the context of a web app:

1. request received - implicit session & sql transaction begins (session per request)
2. command is created and dispatched based on the request
3. command handler loads AR in question using repo and calls appropriate method on the AR
4. within the method an event is raised/published using a bus
5. request terminates - implicit transaction commits if no exceptions in the pipeline

My question(s) are around the event publish, in the context of the implicit transaction failing to commit.  Wouldn't the event being published without the actual state of the AR being updated be a huge issue?  If so, how could this be addressed?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with CQRS and domain events, there are 2 things that matter: idempotency and eventual consistency. IN this context you don't really have an ACID transaction, you have messages that were handled or not. Each message handling is independent (the event doesn't know about the command or other events). The 'transaction' is actually the handling of the sent commands. Usually the event is an outcome of command handling but the 'transaction' ends when the event has been published, not handled.

If the server crashes, the service bus/message processor should detect that a command wasn't sent/handled and should try to re sent it (here the idempontency is important). Same with an event handling.

In your example, you're talking about commit (a concept which is db centric) but there can be 2 commands updating different ARs executing async. If one command fails the other doesn't know about it. This seems difficult to handle but it's quite simple, but the concepts and use cases MUST be properly modeled as you're dealing with the eventual consistency now.

When a command fails from a business point of view (violation of business rules) then a new event is published and its handler will issue a compensatory action (not really that hard as it sounds). All interested parties will subscribe to that event and act accordingly.

When you model the business flow,  and you come up with 2-3 commands which need to be treated as a transaction you need to understand if there's a business relationship between the commands. Some can be unrelated,  but other can actually be part of a saga. So you don't have 3 commands in a transaction you have cmd1 -> event -> cmd 2-> event ->cmd3. only at the end , the 'transaction' is completed.

The business model tells you which case is (that's why proper modelling is important) and that will help you deal with the problems, because you don't have to undo 3 commands and N events.

Comment: "Same with an event handling." This is not right, events are idempotent by nature, actually they should be, in a well design system, they do not change domain business repositories, they might change read models but that does not matter.

Comment: Events don't change anything, event **handlers** might. The service bus might publish the event more than once, the event handler needs to ensure idempotency as well.

Comment: Events handlers should not in any case make business changes, ever. They replicate data, in the services where the event is handled, or initiate a change, i.e.: sagas, which should only subscribe to events and put commands in the bus.

Comment: I didn't say the event handlers SHOULD make business changes, they might change things (outside the domain). The cleanest way is to have  handlers issuing new commands for changing the domain, but after all, it's not a strict rule and it depends on context and developer.

Comment: "it's not a strict rule and it depends on context and developer" This is what I dont agree with, there are rules of course i.e.: saga pattern and many others; events are named in past test for a reason.

Comment: No, there aren't **rules**, there are _principles_ and their implementation depending on the context. And I'm talking about event **handlers** not about the event (the message).

Comment: I know what you are talking about, I know that an event (object) can not change anything, what I dont know is why you are mentioning that which is something I never said. Yes there are rules, patterns and so one, and no, it does not depend on any context, unless the rules are just yours.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue stemmed from the fact that there is essentially a 2 phase "commit".  In this example, P1 = event published, P2 = AR state persisted to the database.  Either of those things happening without the other would cause inconsistencies.

There is no perfect way to solve this particular problem, but I have found promising alternatives utilizing event store mechanisms.

With this approach the AR maintains an internal list of events which have been applied (typically via commands being executed).  Instead of persisting the current state of the AR, these events are persisted, individually, to an event store.  The current state is never persisted, but it can be restored by replaying the events.

This removes the need for 2 phase commit as the event store maintains the state changes, and enables communicating the state changes to observers.